Can one reasonably make inferences about partner's first bid based on the second bid?
With no one vulnerable at matchpoints, my (occasional) partner dealt and bid one diamond with the following:
(s) 752 (h) QT7 (d) AQJ52 (c) A8.
I bid one heart. She re-bid two diamonds, and I reluctantly bid three clubs, a suit in which I was as long as hearts. She rebid three diamonds, and I passed, even though my distribution was 3-5-void-5 (with seven high card points).
Partner said, the she didn't want to raise my (presumed) four card heart suit with only three, and she never dreamed that I had zero diamonds. I said that I had bid two suits, and therefore was more likely to be at least 5-4 hearts-clubs than 4-4, wanted her to choose a round suit and implied shortage in her suit, since I didn't raise two diamonds. Was this (verbal) reply reasonable given the previous bidding?
And was I right to pass based on my mistaken premise that partner had seven diamonds for her bid, on the grounds that 7-0 in diamonds would be better than a (presumed) 5-2 fIt (which was actually 5-3) in hearts?

You really have to teach your partner to ALWAYS rebid 1 NT with a balanced or semi-balanced minimum after opening 1 of a minor. The auction 1D 1H; 1NT 2C; 2H Pass; will work in any system at all that plays 15-17 NT, regardless of what 2C means. The moment the minimum misfit is revealed - the object is to settle quickly in a playable denomination that won't get doubled and as a chance of making.

Egads.
Your partner should have bid 1N over your 1H bid.  The 2D bid promises a 6th diamond (at least not in competition over a 1H response).
You should have passed 2D - your 3C bid promises more strength, at least close to game forcing (some partnerships will play it as game forcing).
Your partner should bid 4H over your 3C bid.

Tom doesn't tell us his hand. Why do we believe that the hand was weak enough to pass 1NT? It could well be invitational. Frankly, based on past questions it may well have merited a game force.

He says it was 3-5-0-5 with 7 hcp - I wouldn't consider T98 AKT98 - T9876 invitational

Ah, I missed the 7 hcp part

My 3 clubs was a "rescue" bid. I put partner on 13 high card points and six diamonds for her two diamond rebid, so we would have 20 between us. My three club bid meant "1) I can't stand diamonds even if you have six so I have 0 or 1; 2) I am 5-5 in the "round" suits so pick the one in which you have three cards. With 20 hcps and a 5-3 fit, we stand to go down one, versus down two in two diamonds with a 6-0 fit (law of total tricks). If we're lucky, our spade shortage might allow us to make three clubs or hearts."

In standard american, your 3C bid is forcing for one round and invitational to game.  How else would you bid Kx AKxxx xx Axxx?

@TomAu Rescue bids are very rare in well-designed bidding systems because constructive bidding is more important -- when you have a misfit, you should stop bidding, rather than raising the level. In this particular instance, partner may have 7 or even 8 diamonds, and 0 clubs. If you feel you must rescue, you can rebid your hearts, which shows more hearts than you have but at least doesn't promise values.

@AlexanderWoo nails it, but I'll show the inferences.
Re/Bid NT

Almost all systems have a "NT ladder"; a large number of sequences of bids that show a balanced opening hand of a limited (2 or 3 HCP) strength.  It is just easier to bid if you use them if possible.This example: opener can treat her hand as balanced (even with a strong 5-card minor) and show "12-14 balanced, 4 or 5 diamonds, not 4 hearts"(1); or she can treat her hand as a one-suited diamond hand and show "12-16/bad 17, 6 diamonds, reason to avoid 1NT (probably shortness, likely in hearts)". Which one will it be easier to evaluate your hand (whatever it is) against?
This advantage is so strong that players over time are lumping more and more hands into "balanced".  5hearts-3-3-2?  Sure.  6-diamonds-3-2-2?  Absolutely.  2=2=2=bad 7?  Some will. 2=4=2=5 16 count?  Many will open 1NT because 1♣-1♠ leaves them without a comfortable call.  Open suit? Two?  Sure, partner has a stopper, or they don't and it might not get found, or partner will put us somewhere where it doesn't matter.
Who wants to play in a minor anyway?  Especially if game is available, it's likely in NT (2).  So use the NT ladder to show both parts of one's hand rather than focussing on one.
Frankly, I wrote something in the last century that said "your rebids show 6-card suits".  Yes, there are exceptions, and there are times where every other call is a bigger lie, but it's a good thing to assume in general.  What about this hand wants one to promise 6 diamonds when they can show 12-14 balanced instead?

I play a weak (12-14) 1NT in my most regular partnership.  Playing that, I wouldn't dream of making any call but 1NT with that hand.  ♦AQJ52?  So?  The "NT ladder" is that strong.
If she rebids 1NT as she should, you can place the contract.  If 2♣ is natural for you, great, try it (partner will correct to hearts).  It isn't for me, so I'd bid 2♥ and hope to survive.  Magic this time.
Rescue
Don't (at least undoubled). Only rarely is it possible, and it erodes partnership confidence even when it works.  If you pull partner's NF call (as opposed to showing extras), it's not because you're afraid of leaving her there, it's because your pull is better, whether it's "my suit is longer than yours (even with bad support)", or "if we're going to play a misfit at the 2 level, let's at least score +110 instead of +90 if it makes".
Especially avoid running when it raises a level.  As A.Woo points out, 3♣ should be forward-going, not "2♦ is bad, a random suit at the 3 level will be better".
The time to rescue?  1♦-1♥; 2♦-p-(X); p-(p).  Now, if you play it, redouble for rescue.  But know that at least once, I've seen this auction get "rescued" into 3♦ doubled, which was the best result!
2♦ probably doesn't play well; but the opponents might come in.  They might double; they might bid spades and partner might compete in hearts.  Still better than the table result.
3♦
This is an even more awful call than 2♦.  You have not raised partner's "6-card" suit; how many diamonds can you have?
Also, the way to "not have to rebid 5-card suits" is for partner to show secondary support "the second time around".  After 3♣, opener has what could possibly be the best possible heart holding: QJx.  Surely you didn't decide this is the right time to show 3=4=1=5 or 2=4=1=6?  Show partner your hearts, on the way.  I'm not as strong as A. Woo - I think a poor 2♦ hand should show it, so I'd bid 3♥.  He might be right - showing clubs might upgrade this hand to a "good" 12-16; but even 3♥ is better than rebidding those diamonds again!
Even 4♥, assuming a not-awful break, will score better than 3♦, especially if they don't find a trump lead.
Summary
So, lots of ways to get to a better contract than you did, from both sides.
Why does partner do this?  Because their partners will never raise their diamonds, even after 1♦-1♥; 2♣ because "but partner, you could have 3" (it's even worse when they open 1♣ instead!) So they have to "show they have a real suit" when they have 5 - especially this strong a 5.  Because their usual partners, too, will not show delayed support "in case your suit is longer".
Why do you do this?  Because you can't trust your partners to have a suit playable (even if uncomfortably) opposite a void when they rebid it, either.
Trust your partner; show trust in your partner; bid such that partner can trust you, and expect them to show it.  Take your bad results when the RNGod gives them to you - even if, this time, there was a better place to land.  Take your bad results when, this time, it turns out you couldn't trust partner (yet.  That's where we can have a useful post-mortem). Your results will improve, and so will their confidence (and their bidding, at least in time!)
It's not easy; and some never learn.  And it will absolutely hurt while you're both unlearning the habits.  And it will absolutely hurt after you've unlearned them, and you play again with a partner who you can't trust.  But it is best for your game.
(1) this is close to a 2♥ bid for some players - double-honour third, a ruffing value, and an empty suit?  I'd expect many to bid 2♥ with (s) 72 (h) QT7 (d) AQJ52 (c) A85.
(2) Even more so at matchpoints.  Ever heard "at matchpoints, 5 of a minor is a slam try?"  I describe the choice as "If you don't know, bid 3NT.  If 5♣ is the better option, you'll know."  Remember that 3NT= is two tricks less and the same score as 5♣; and 3NT+1 is two tricks less and beats 5♣+1.

Note: Even if you did decide that this was the time to show 3=4=1=5 or 2=4-1=6, you must have good values and so your next call over partner's 3H showing secondary support will be 3S (I don't have a spade stopper) or 3NT (I do have a spade stopper), and you will find 3NT or 5C as appropriate (or even a Moysian 4H).

I would certainly expect partner to have at least 6 diamonds, at most 3 spades, and likely not 3 hearts. Certainly they should have a minimum opener. Example hands would be Kxx xx AQJxxx Qx, or KQx x KQJxxx xxx, or x Axx KQJxxx xxx. With partner's actual hand, their first rebid should be 1NT.
With a balanced hand with opening values, you should endeavor to show your balanced shape and point range with your first two bids, unless it is necessary to show a fit instead. With 12-14 hcp, your plan is to rebid 1NT at round 2.
You don't tell us what your hand is, but I can infer it has invitational values since you rebid 3C (a forcing bid) but passed on the third round (so you don't have a game force). Probably after partner's 1NT rebid, you should bid 2D (new minor forcing, a common conventional agreement). Partner should bid 3H (showing 3-card support and a maximum), so you should end up in 4H.

You ask:

Can one reasonably make inferences about partner's first bid based on the second bid?

and then produce a fairly specific example of one particular sequence. (Ruds and Alex have dealt with that sequence in detail).
The answer to the question as asked is of course, emphatically, "yes".
The classic example is when partner opens and subsequently shows a second suit. You can immediately deduce that the first suit is as long as the second and in almost all cases (drat those pesky 4-4-4-1 hands), that the first suit is at least five cards in length. Playing Acol, where an opening of one of a major only promises four cards, that is a valuable inference.
Another, more contrived example would be partner opening a weak 1NT (12-14) and, when asked for aces, showing 3. You can conclude that opener has exactly one suit containing no card higher than the queen.
Bidding tells a story. Each new page can reveal information about a character introduced in the first chapter.
